# Manger field values is overwriting after incremental crawl in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user-profile-property, userprofilemanager

Step 1: we ran full crawl successfully.
Step 2: we updated manually manager values for 10 users.
Step 3: removed mapping for **manager** in **Manage User Properties**.
Step 4: Again we ran the incremental crawl.

After incremental crawl completed,manager field value is showing empty for 10 users  in the SharePoint User Profile.

we removed mapping for Manager even though why it was showing empty value once incremental crawl is completed.

Can any one give response on this ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that you actually removed the mapping. The page UI is terrible. Once you click remove (or add) you have to confirm it in the page before closing the page. I suspect that the mapping is still there.

Failing that you can try to troubleshoot the connection in the miisclient utility, though the best approach is to remove the connection and start again.

Comment: I verified it multiple times,but still same problem.

Comment: Did you try deleting the connection and recreating it?

Comment: Yes we tried with multiple times,even through no use..........

Comment: I would file a ticket with Microsoft, I have not seen this behavior.

Comment: I just tested this on a fresh environment and removing the connection on the manager field prevented changes from AD being imported. I would file a ticket with MS

Comment: Thanks.Please give updates,if you find any information on this.

Comment: I don't plan on doing anything further as it is working for me. For your environment I would contact Microsoft Support.